# How to know if array count is incrementing in didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gmsmapview

I am new to Swift. I am using Google Maps Sdk's method didUpdateLocations to draw a path on the map.

I am working on a section regarding the array count. I want to run some functions if the array count is increasing. I am storing lat and long in two arrays.

```
var latarray = [Double]()
var longarray = [Double]()

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  
           locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        myMapView.clear()
   
        
        if (self.latarray.count != 0 ) {
        longarray.append(long)
        latarray.append(lat)
        print ("lat array is \(latarray)count is \(latarray.count)")
        print ("long array is \(longarray)count is \(longarray.count)")
        }
            else {
            Print("array not increasing ")
               }
         let location = locations.last
        self.lat = (location?.coordinate.latitude)!
        self.long = (location?.coordinate.longitude)!

     
        let currtlocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        
    }
```

Is there any operator which can show if the array content if array count is increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has something called property observers that you can use to execute code when a property is set/changed. They are `willSet` and `didSet` and they work fine for arrays as well. You can read more about properties and property observers [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#)

An example

```
struct Test {
    var array = [Int]() {
        didSet {
            print("Array size is \(array.count)")
        }
    }
}

var test = Test()

test.array.append(1)
test.array.append(1)
test.array.append(1)
test.array = []
```

prints

> Array size is 1
>   Array size is 2
>   Array size is 3
>   Array size is 0

Comment: DId you mean didset can help me to know changes in the array right ?? @ joakim Danielson

Comment: Yes that is what I mean